# MySQL product of multiple result set

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have multiple result set, each with same number of column.
but I may have 5 result sets, or 10 result sets.

I need to do a product from these result sets.
In mathematics should be written as 
A * B * C * D ... * N

Can I achieve this using SQL statement?
By far I know I can do this if I have a specific number of Self Joins.
I can do something like

```
SELECT tcs1.*, tbl1.*, tbl2.*, tbl3.*, CONCAT(tbl1.actual_id, tbl2.actual_id, tbl3.actual_id) as new_test_case_name
FROM test_config_sets tcs
LEFT JOIN test_config_sets tcs1 ON tcs.test_case = tcs1.test_case
CROSS JOIN (SELECT tcd.actual_id 
    FROM test_config_profiles tcp 
    LEFT JOIN test_config_data tcd ON tcp.id = tcd.profile
    WHERE tcp.id = 649) as tbl1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT tcd.actual_id 
    FROM test_config_profiles tcp 
    LEFT JOIN test_config_data tcd ON tcp.id = tcd.profile
    WHERE tcp.id = 188) as tbl2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT tcd.actual_id 
    FROM test_config_profiles tcp 
    LEFT JOIN test_config_data tcd ON tcp.id = tcd.profile
    WHERE tcp.id = 189) as tbl3
WHERE tcs.test_config_profile = 649 AND tcs1.test_case = 400
GROUP BY new_test_case_name
ORDER BY tcs1.test_case ASC, tcs1.sequence ASC;
```

In this example I have specific 3 sets of data, tbl1, tbl2, and tbl3.
How can I expand it to be dynamic enough to return me result even I have N sets of data?

Comment: Yes! Cross JOIN will do

Answer (score 0):

CROSS JOIN can be used as below:

```
SELECT tcs.*, tcp.*, tcd.*
FROM test_config_sets tcs
CROSS JOIN test_config_profiles tcp
CROSS JOIN test_config_data  tcd
```

If the tables have for example, 2 rows, 4 rows and 5 rows, the output resultset would contain 2*4*5 rows. In `CROSS JOIN` each row of a table is joined with each row other table it is joined with.

Comment: tcp and tcd will both contains thousands or millions of data
thats why i need to perform filtering of their data.

SELECT tcd.actual_id 
    FROM test_config_profiles tcp 
    LEFT JOIN test_config_data tcd ON tcp.id = tcd.profile
    WHERE tcp.id = 649

Dynamically I could have N sets of data like this, and I would only interest to CROSS JOIN these result sets